# How do I insert a smiley face in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

This seems simple but I need to insert a black-and-white smily face similiar to this image. Are there any glyphs like this on the Mac. I got this from Microsoft Word it automatically does it when you type :)

[image]

Comment: It's just a font.. like Wingdings or Webdings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smiley glyph in Word is a streamlined mashup of AutoCorrect and Wingdings. Chances are really good that you have Wingdings (since you have Word), so you can insert it via the Glyphs panel as needed. Other fonts sometimes have smileys; check the glyphs palette for each font to see what's available.

As an alternative, you could draw your own smile in InDesign and then just copy and paste that inline while you're typing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a Unicode equivalent of about every Wingding in the Wingdings font. Check out [this site](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html):

> ☺ 9786    U+263A  White smiling face

Answer (score 0):

The capital letter "J" in Wingdings is the smiley face. :)

Answer (score 0):

To revive this question, another option is to use an icon-font like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) which has a load of useful icons, including a smiley. This can be used in combination with the glyphs panel in InDesign.